# How do I store and access token globally from Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, token

I'm working on a dashboard web application that uses the `grant_type=client_credentials` to get Bearer Tokens to gain access to its resources.

The plan is to have the MVC controllers make calls to the API on behalf of the client browser.

The ajax requests from the browser will hit the MVC controllers and then the API calls are made. Results are then fed back to the client as JSON and handles in react.

The client should never communicate directly with the API and doesn't need to login to see the dashboard.

When applications loads for the first time it requests server for a token using client credentials stored in `appsettings.json`. I'm able to get the token but I don't know where to store and access it globally. I need global access to this token so that after 20 min or so I can send `refresh_token` request to the server and use it in all subsequent calls to the API to get data.

Can I store it in `HttpContext` and use it from there?

Currently I'm requesting token as follows:

```
public class TokensController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public TokensController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // Get Token
        public static async Task<Token> GetToken(Uri authenticationUrl, Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(authenticationCredentials);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(authenticationUrl, content);

            if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(responseString);

            return token;
        }

        public IActionResult GetAccessToken()
        {

            Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials_np = Configuration.GetSection("SomeEnvironment:Credentials").GetChildren().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            Token token_np = GetToken(new Uri(Configuration["SomeEnvironment:URL"]), authenticationCredentials_np).Result;

            return Ok(token_np);
        }

    }
```

Any suggestions/thoughts?

Comment: if you only want one token to use on behalf of all users of the website, you could grab the token and write it to a text file in your project, then read it back from the text file. And if you need to refresh the token, you can store a datetime in the text file of when the token was created so that you can check for a necessary refresh. Or you could store it in a database with a timestamp, or you could create a token for each user and store it in session on the webserver. There are many options available.

Comment: If using dependency injection, you can have a service that provides these values. Register it as a singleton and it will live for the life of the app and be able to take care of the refresh details on its own. However, this would occur once per app instance, so do you need a way to share this between instances? That would require a more complicated setup

Comment: @RyanWilson It will not be a single token every time server issues a new token when you send a refresh request. I need a global variable which can be rewritable after every 20 min with a refreshed token.

Comment: @ps2goat I really don't need to share this between instances. There will be one token and it will be refresh periodically. Multiple users can view this dashboard but I don't think each user will need its own token.

Comment: Have you looked into memory caching?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Tyddlywink seems promising I will try this tomorrow :)

Comment: @JKLM I gave you options on how to store it "globally". You can keep it in a database with a timestamp so you can know when to refresh, I think that would be my first option. As I said another would be to write the token with it's creation datetime into a text file which is accessible by the web app.

Comment: @RyanWilson I guess storing a token in the database is not really required in this case. Just the global variable which holds this token and after 20 min I can run scheduler which will run `refresh_token` request which will replace the variable with a refreshed token is sufficient.